# Azure mobile as storage

Tags: java, android, azure

I am using azure mobile service as a storage platform for an android app I am developing. How can I select data from a table that is a month or less old? This is the query in which I want to add that feature to:

```
final MobileServiceList<Crime> assaultNum = mToDoTable.where().field("county").eq(countyString).execute().get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query selects rows where the county column is equal to Kildare South and the month in the date column is equal to march(03). So the it should be :

```
final MobileServiceList<Crime> assaultNum = mToDoTable.where().field("county").eq("Kildare South")
                        .and().month("date").eq(03).execute().get();
```